# Number of real singular points

Tags: real-algebraic-geometry

Let $f\in\mathbb{R}[X,Y]$ be a real polynomial in two variables. Are there bounds on the number of singular points of $f$ which take into account that $f$ might have high degree but be rather sparse?
For example a what is a bound on the number of singular points of a  polynomial of the from $f=X^{100}+Y^{100}+ $Terms of order at most $4$.

Comment: There is a bound in terms of Hodge numbers (Varchenko), and the latter can be estimated in terms of the Newton polygon (Khovansky ?). Try a search for "fewnomials".